# How do I read & write an integer from a file?

Tags: bash

I need a script or one-liner to read an integer from a file, add 10, set my monitor brightness, and write the new value back to the file. I have it working in AppleScript, but it's rather slow, so was hoping to recreate in `bash`.

Basically:

1. Read value `X` from a file
2. Increment `X` by 10
3. If `X > 100` then set `X` to 100.
4. Set brightness to `X` using `ddcctl -d 1 -b $X`
5. Write `X` back to the file (replacing)

Comment: "*I need X*" is not a question. (Have you tried hiring a programmer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Directory where this script is located
#
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

declare x=$(cat "${DIR}/path/to/file")
x=$((x+10))
if [[ ${x} -gt 100 ]]; then
    x=100
fi
ddcctl -d 1 -b ${x}
echo "${x}" > "${DIR}/path/to/file"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @MattMc, works great!

Comment: Glad I could help